# MySQL (via phpmyadmin) filter for punctuation marks

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, punctuation

I have been given the assignment for my upcoming test and I need to search for the titles with punctuation marks in them in a database filled with movie details.

My only idea is to look up the names with specific punctuation mark in them with MySQL's IN operator.

```
SELECT title
FROM `movies`
WHERE title LIKE "%.%" OR title LIKE "%" [- and so on]
```

or another way:

```
SELECT title
FROM `movies`
WHERE title IN (., %) [- and so on]
```

However, it is logically not correct.
As well as when I filter for the "."/dot charachter/, it gives back titles with "i" in them as well.

Can you please help me?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is wrong with your first query, which is perhaps not optimal, but nevertheless looks logically correct?

Comment: correct, yes and gives a good result, however, you can't possibly know all types of punctuation marks from a database with thousands of entries; that is why I am looking for another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One general approach to finding all titles having one or more punctuation characters would be to use `REGEXP` with the pattern `[[:punct:]]`:

```sql
SELECT title
FROM movies
WHERE title REGEXP '[[:punct:]]';
```